# hostname -f shows reverse DNS twice

Tags: email, dns, hostname, sendmail

On a Debian 4.7.2-5, I got some problems sending mail correctly with sendmail. It appears that ELHO sender is different from domain name.
When I ask machine for its hostname FQDN :

```
hostname -f
```

I got as answer **mydomain.com.mydomain.com**

**UPDATE : content of /etc/hosts**

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1       mydomain.com

1.2.3.4         mydomain.com

# OVH stuff , I don't use IPV6
2001:41D0:2:97b9::      nsXXXX.ip-1-2-3.eu      nsXXX

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#(added automatically by netbase upgrade)

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

**UPDATE : content of /etc/nsswitch.conf** (hosts part) AND **/etc/mail/service.switch** (identical)

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Where does this can come from?

Many thanks for your answers, I'm bit stuck on this one.

Comment: Could you post lines with mydomain.com in your `/etc/hosts`? Does your DNS domain `mydomain.com` contain wildcard records?

Comment: I just did in main question. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Could you include `hosts` lines from `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and  `/etc/mail/*.switch` files?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's done and for the record, only one *.switch file, service.switch.